# How change data in table format to a graph in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

I have data in a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GILz6.png).
each column is a month and each row is a year.
The data consists of improvements over the year and I try to put it in a graph to see the improvements with a line in a graph, but the only method I could find was to remake the table and this time i would need to make a column for the whole date and than the second column for the improvements numbers, but adding data and comparing such numbers also be in the table itself becomes much more difficult, is there another way?

I am using excel and I'm also fine with just showing the years as intervals instead of years and months.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your existing table as where you enter and view your data, and use a Power Query and Pivot Chart to visualize the data. These can be refreshed whenever you add new data.

To create a power query to reformat your data, select any cell in your table then use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range. This will open the Power Query editor.

Now select the Year column and use Transform>Any Column>Unpivot Columns>Unpivot other columns:

[image]

After you've done that, you'll see that the data are now stacked in the right format:

[image]

You can right click columns and rename them. I'll rename Attribute to Month and Value to Improvement.

At this point, you can use Home>Close & Load>Close & Load To>Pivot Chart to create a chart on the existing sheet or on a new sheet.

However, you may find it useful to add a column that expresses the year and month as a date. This will give you more options in your chart(s).

To do that, use Add Column>General>Custom Column and configure it like this:

[image]

Here's that formula:

```
Date.FromText(Number.ToText([year]) & "-" & [Month] & "-01")
```

After adding this column, I use Home>Close & Load>Close & Load To>Pivot Chart and put it on a new sheet. I can then create a chart like this:

[image]

There are of course many other better options for such a chart.

Good luck!